# how to add more plots to same axes in subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'd like to add multiple plots to a specific subplot with the same axis. So far I managed to do that with by just repeatedly callign `plt.[some_plotting_function]` after activating the corresponding `plt.subplot(xxx)` like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'o-')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0,0], 'o-')

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot([0, 1], [1, 0], 'o-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I get the warning

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
```

It sounds like the same code will behave differently in the future. How will I be able to achieve the same result as with the code above in the future?

Comment: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2)`. Then use `axs[0].plot` and `axs[1].plot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use this code, but refactor it to use returned axes instead of referring to subplots, like:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'o-')

ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
ax2.plot([0, 1], [0,0], 'o-')

ax1.plot([0, 1], [1, 0], 'o-')
plt.show()
```

You can see instead of referring to first subplot, I use axis returned by the first subplot call.

Edit: this is a similar approach to the one mentioned in the comments, but it stays close to your original workflow.